# How to inspect the React native android UI elements in android emulator?

Tags: react-native

Am running the app in the android emulator and, I want to `Preview/Inspect` the UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can check using android studio.
please follow the step:
Tools> android > Android Monitor Device 
Open another view

in This view show camera icon in left side panel.
right side of camera icon another icon called "Dump View hierarchy for UI Automator" press on it.

then you can check.

Comment: check my solution?

Comment: Thank you. Yes but it will take Screen shot and then we can inspect, but still am unable to change the styles(As easy as we do in web browsers) and try some trail and errors.

Comment: i will give you answer as you check which native component use in React-native.  you can check status every stage use console.log() or console .warn() method to check at that point status.